# Serve content from a different domain without changing the URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, url, dns

Is there a way to show content on a website from a different domain, without changing the URL. Considering I own and control both Domains and FTPs.

**Example:**
second-site.com/about, without changing its URL, will show content from first-site.com/about. It gets even trickier, the about page will have the equivalent of URL in another language. So /about may be /uber-uns (in German), and I have to know this somehow so the URL can point to the specific content.

The reason the client wants this setup is because he's running a multi-lang website offering travel packages. He has a ton of prices for hotels and airlines which are the same for both languages, so naturally, he wants to enter them once (contradicting my initial proposal to have two separate CMS's).

Is there anyway to achieve this via htaccess? I'm using ExpressionEngine which is based on CodeIgniter/PHP.

I've researched on Stack and Online, but haven't found a safe or standard way to achieve this.

Comment: Both domain names should point to the same website, and showing the correct language should be handled in website code.

Comment: Can you please elaborate @DusanBajic?